# jquery is not defined in webpages that are loaded from assets directory

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, android-webview

I have a bunch of html files that come with my app and are bundlet in the assets folder.

I load a page like this to my webview:

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

     @Override
     public void onConsoleMessage(String message, int lineNumber, String sourceID) {
        Log.d("MyApplication", message + " -- From line " + lineNumber + " of " + sourceID);
     }
});
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/_lib/jquery-1.6.1.min.js");
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/" + page);
```

Now if page contains this:

```
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src = "_lib/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script src = "_lib/jquery.easing-1.3.js"></script>

<!-- iosSlider plugin -->
<script src = "javascript/jquery.iosslider.js"></script>
```

I get the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined at file:///android_asset/javascript/jquery.iosslider.js:32
```

If I load the same page from a webserver the javascript works as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be the _ in front of the lib folder. 
The jquery.iosslider.js file is executed without a problem.

I removed the _ in the folder name and also in the html files and now everything just works.